# restkit.h file not found when archiving using xcode 6

Tags: ios, restkit, xcode6.3, archiving

i need your help everyone. i am having an error when archiving an app with restkit. On build it is perfectly ok, but when archiving it generates an error below:

1. [App location...]/AppDelegate.m:3:9: 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found
2. [App location...]/RestKit/Code/CoreData/CoreData.h:22:9: 'ObjectMapping.h' file not found

Cheers!

Comment: So tell us how you've added RestKit to your project, and what build settings are different between Debug and Release

Comment: Debug and release has same settings only the provisioning profiles are different. And i have added restkit by dragging the xproj file into my project

Comment: Are you able to use cocoapods? It's probably an issue with the header search paths...

Comment: I did not use cocoapods. I just copy the restkt folder from a working project. Here's my header search path: "$SOURCE_ROOT/RestKit/Build/Headers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! the cause is that my Build Settings > Architecture is not set properly.

Here's what i did:
App submission: arm64 and armv7
Simulator: armv7
Device: arm64

Answer (score 0):

If you can, switch to using CocoaPods.

Update your release header search paths to include `"$(SRCROOT)/Build/Headers"` and `"$(BUILD_ROOT)/../"`.

Comment: Thanks Man! i found a solution to my problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue, to change the Header Search Path

```
"$(SOURCE_ROOT)/RestKit-RestKit-c19a500/Build"
```

Note : "RestKit-RestKit-c19a500" this is my RestKit folder name.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, if you're using Core Data mappings, make sure to check if your Search Paths (Your Project -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Release) folders really exist. If not, just update them to the real folder.

Don't forget to include "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/RestKit/CoreData" folder, as setting the recursive flag on Headers/Public/RestKit doesn't seem to work!